# UTF-8 is not working Even after charater set is configured in slf4j logback.xml

Tags: log4j, logback, slf4j, log4j2

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <target>System.out</target>
    <encoder>
    <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>%X{akkaTimestamp} %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>log/akka.log</file>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>log/tests.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>250</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="akka" level="INFO" />

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

Arabic characters are not coming in log file. Characters are coming as

**************************************************message: {"text":"???? ??? ?? ???? ?? ????? ?????? ??."}***********************************

Comment: Are the characters showing correctly in the console, but not in the log file? Can you give more details about how you're testing? Also, it's highly unlikely that you are trying to use log4j, log4j2, and logback simultaneously; please update your tags to the logging framework you're actually using.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... It is working after adding <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
   <charset>UTF-8</charset>
   <outputPatternAsHeader>true</outputPatternAsHeader>
   <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n
   </pattern>
  </encoder>

Comment: If you've found the solution, please post it as the answer and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 3):

It is working after adding

```
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
    <charset>UTF-8</charset>
    <outputPatternAsHeader>true</outputPatternAsHeader> 
    <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n </pattern>    
</encoder>
```

**Full File**

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <target>System.out</target>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
    <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <outputPatternAsHeader>true</outputPatternAsHeader> 
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>log/akka.log</file>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>log/tests.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>250</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <outputPatternAsHeader>true</outputPatternAsHeader>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="akka" level="INFO" />

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```